# keras model not loading

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict

I've read through similar questions on this and am still stumped. On the same computer, I am training a model and saving with

```
model.save(model_location)
type(model)
```

```
keras.engine.functional.Functional
```

Then, I am loading the model with

```
model = keras.models.load_model(model_location)
 # model = tf.saved_model.load(model_location) results in the same
type(model)
```

`<class 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject'>`

and getting the following error when calling `model.predict(X)`

`AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'`

```
tf.saved_model.contains_saved_model(model_location)

true
```

tensorflow-gpu == 2.7.0
keras == 2.8.0

```
This is on Windows, and the same environment on my Linux machine does not produce this error.

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, working case:

Comment: model = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50( weights=None )
model.save("./xxx")
mdl = keras.models.load_model("./xxx")
mdl.predict(  )

Comment: May be your model is not `Keras` kind, such as converted with model2 = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to solve this is to get the Keras API, by wrapping it inside a KerasLayer in a Sequential model as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer("saved/model/path")
])
model.build(<input_shape>)
```

Now the model supports all Keras API like predict, summary, etc, and this now should work:

```
model.predict(X)
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thnaks!